# Convert C-Source image dump into original image

Tags: c++, c, image-processing, gimp

I have created with GIMP a C-Source image dump like the following:

```
/* GIMP RGBA C-Source image dump (example.c) */

static const struct {
  guint      width;
  guint      height;
  guint      bytes_per_pixel; /* 2:RGB16, 3:RGB, 4:RGBA */ 
  guint8     pixel_data[304 * 98 * 2 + 1];
} example= {
  304, 98, 2,
  "\206\061\206\061..... }
```

Is there a way to read this in GIMP again in order to get back the original image? because it doesn't seem possible.
Or does it exist a tool that can do this back-conversion?

**EDITED**

Following some suggestion I tried to write a simple C programme to make the reverse coversion ending up with something very similar to another code found on internet but both dont work:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "imgs_press.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int fd;
    char *name = "orignal_img.pnm";
    fd = open(name, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0644);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("open failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (dup2(fd, 1) == -1) {
        perror("dup2 failed"); 
        exit(1);
    }

    // file descriptor 1, i.e. stdout, now points to the file
    // "helloworld" which is open for writing
    // You can now use printf which writes specifically to stdout

  printf("P2\n");
  printf("%d %d\n", press_high.width, press_high.height);
  for(int x=0; x<press_high.width * press_high.height * 2; x++) {
    printf("%d ", press_high.pixel_data[x]);
  }
}
```

As suggested by n-1-8e9-wheres-my-share-m, maybe I need to manipulate the pixels usign the correct decode, but I have no idea how to do that, does anybody have other suggestions?

The image I got is indeed distorted:
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239844/discussion-on-question-by-navy1978-convert-c-source-image-dump-into-original-ima).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

If you want to decode the RGB565 and write a NetPBM format PNM file without using **ImageMagick**, you can do this:

```
#include <stdint.h>   /* for uint8_t */
#include <stdio.h>    /* for printf */

/* tell compiler what those GIMP types are */
typedef int guint;
typedef uint8_t guint8;

#include <YOURGIMPIMAGE>

int main(){

   int w = gimp_image.width;
   int h = gimp_image.height;
   int i;
   uint16_t*  RGB565p = (uint16_t*)&(gimp_image.pixel_data);

   /* Print P3 PNM header on stdout */
   printf("P3\n%d %d\n255\n",w, h);

   /* Print RGB pixels, ASCII, one RGB pixel per line */
   for(i=0;i<w*h;i++){
      uint16_t RGB565 = *RGB565p++;
      uint8_t r = (RGB565 & 0xf800) >> 8;
      uint8_t g = (RGB565 & 0x07e0) >> 3;
      uint8_t b = (RGB565 & 0x001f) << 3;
      printf("%d %d %d\n", r, g ,b);
   }
}
```

Compile with:

```
clang example.c
```

And run with:

```
./a.out > result.pnm
```

I have not tested it too extensively beyond your sample image, so you may want to make a test image with some reds, greens, blues and shades of grey to ensure that all my bit-twiddling is correct.

**Original Answer**

The easiest way to get your image back would be... to let **ImageMagick** do it.

So, take your C file and add a `main()` to it that simply writes the 304x98x2 bytes starting at `&(example.pixel_data)` to stdout:

Compile it with something like:

```
clang example.c -o program    # or with GCC
gcc example.c -o program
```

Then run it, writing to a file for **ImageMagick** with:

```
./program > image.bin
```

And tell **ImageMagick** its size, type and where it is and what you want as a result:

```
magick -size 304x98 RGB565:image.bin result.png
```

---

I did a quick, not-too-thorough test of the following code and it worked fine for an image I generated with GIMP. Note it doesn't handle alpha/transparency but that could be added if necessary. Save it as `program.c`:

```
#include <unistd.h>   /* for write() */
#include <stdint.h>   /* for uint8_t */

/* tell compiler what those GIMP types are */
typedef int guint;
typedef uint8_t guint8;

<PASTE YOUR GIMP FILE HERE>

int main(){

   /* Work out how many bytes to write */
   int nbytes = example.width * example.height * 2;

   /* Write on stdout for redirection to a file - may need to reopen in binary mode if on Windows */
   write(1, &(example.pixel_data), nbytes);
}
```

If I run this with the file you provided via Google Drive I get:

[image]

Comment: There is no need to manually paste the GIMP file. Simply use an `#include "example.c"`.

Comment: @thebusybee I was suggesting expanding OP's `example.c` he already has and that is the filename in the `clang` and `gcc` commands I suggested... but I do take your point.

Comment: I have tried that but it doest work, your suggestion is equal to this: https://gist.github.com/svenk/a56a468ec25ddd187b8463f97fd118ee#gistcomment-3831258 but it doest work , the reuslt is an image distorted, I have done what you told me:
convert -size 304x98 source.bin result.png

Comment: BTW the image is identify by magicks like : "PGM 304x98 304x98+0+0 8-bit Grayscale Gray 212071B 0.000u 0:00.000"

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have updated my quesiton with the code I used, it seems the code I write is not ok, some decodification of the pixel is needed

Comment: My code is not equivalent to the github code because a) mine works b) mine deals with RGB565 data c) mine doesn't write a PNM. You cannot possibly have a PGM file either if you did what I said because I said to create a PNG file. I have no idea why you have posted some code that doesn't work when I gave you code that does.

Comment: Please share your actual GIMP file so we can see what we are dealing with. Maybe use Google Drive or Dropbox if it's too big for Stack Overflow. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell this is the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YBphg5_V6M2FA3HWcaFZT4fHqD6yeEOl/view?usp=sharing it contains the same image in two different resolutions, I have other files I need to covert back.

Comment: Sorry the late reply, I have been busy... Just tested your code and indeed you were right it worked like a charme. I have accepted your reply ! Thank you. can you please tell me:
1) how can I manage the transparency, 2) where  can I learn  how to do those pizel manipulation? I mena how do you know you have to execute the & and >> operator with those values in order to get the RGB ? thank you very much ! very appreciated!